# Using countif to add up unique terms, but only if unique data in the same row says so

Tags: google-sheets, countif, array-formulas

I'm making a data chart using some formula I found to add up unique data from two columns and return them to one, followed by a count of the number of times those unique items occur. It looks like this.

> =ArrayFormula(unique(transpose(split(concatenate(C3:C151&char(9),D3:D151&char(9)),char(9)))))
>
> =COUNTIF($C$3:$D$151;A166)

However, now I only want it to count up the unique term if it first checks the cell a column next to it in the same row, if that cell has two out of the 5 unique terms that appear there.

How can I add this condition to the count if?

EDIT: Resolved by a man named Yogi Anand.

=ArrayFormula(sum((C3:D151=A170)*((F3:F151="Baby")+(F3:F151="Basic"))))

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer:

> Resolved by a man named Yogi Anand.
>
> `=ArrayFormula(sum((C3:D151=A170)*((F3:F151="Baby")+(F3:F151="Basic"))))`